# Nurbs curve (2D) Length & Linear Sampling

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I have a Nurbs curve (Ctrl Points, Knot Vector, Weights & 3rd or 4th degree). I am able to compute the length by sampling along the curve using a parameter t [0, 1]. Computing the sum of the distances along the curve gives an approximate length of the curve.

1. Is there a better way to compute the length of the curve?
2. Linear sampling: I would like to sample the curve linearly such that the distance between the first sample t = t0 = 0 to t = t1 is S1 and the last sample between t n-1 to tn = 1 is S2 and all the samples in between have lengths that interpolate linearly from S1 to S2.

S1 and S2 are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The curve length follows the equation

```
ds / dt = √(x'²(t) + y'²(t))
```

where `s` is the curvilinear abscissa, `t` the curve parameter and the derivatives are taken on `t`.

What you are willing to do amounts to constructing the function `t(s)` and imposing your values of `s`. This is conveniently done by writing the differential equation

```
dt / ds = 1 / √(x'²(t) + y'²(t))
```

and integrating it numerically, for example with Runge-Kutta.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sampling as you do, instead of pairs, work by the triples of points, interpreting them as arcs *passing through* those three points.

You will get much smaller approximation error with the same spacing of the sampling points, vs. the straight line segments.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the length of a parametrized curve c(u)=(x(u), y(u)) you can use the general formula.

[image]

see [curvilinear abscissa from wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscisse_curviligne)

You explicitly know x(u) and y(u) since
[image]

[NURBS from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline)

I believe you have the formula of the derivative of the rational basis functions. Therefore you have x'(u) and y'(u). Then you can either integrate using simpson's rule or use gauss points specifically to integrate rational polynomial or better yet use your favorite symbolic calculus tool (maple, wolfram,...) to compute exactly the integral.

Comment: Only problem with using maple / Wolfram is that you get a result but not in C++ :)

Comment: I mean use maple or wolfram to get the exact formula for the length L with a specific C(u) by doing symbolic calculus and then recode or use code conversion to produce c++ code.

Comment: calculating C(u), C'(u) from basis functions is not numerically stable though.